Why can $ (-1)^1$ have different answers?
If you count $(-1)^1$ normally, it is just -1. But if you substitute 1 with 2/2, then it is $(-1)^{2/2}$ and if you separate 2/2 into $2\cdot 1/2$ then it is $((-1)^2)^{1/2}$. If you count this you will end up with $√1= 1$. Why does this happen? Can you not apply the laws of exponents this way?

There are two values of $\sqrt{1}$.

Rational exponents don't have the usual rules once you introduce complex numbers.

Please, don't use unusual characters. MathJax has almost any symbol you need. In this case, use \cdot instead of •

@Randall: $\sqrt{1}$ has only one value, as $\sqrt{...}$ stands for the positive square root of a number.

In the middle of that you used an exponent property $a^{bc}=(a^b)^c$. This is only valid if $a$ is nonnegative. And a few other special circumstances. So there is no justification for the side of your argument that ends with value $1$.

+1 for an easily understood answer to a very frequently asked question on this site.

Hmm... perhaps we need an entry for $a^{bc} = (a^b)^c$ on the list of "Common Questions" post on meta. It's not quite like other exponentiation entries on that list.
